# Where should I initialize resources for an Android Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, architecture, live-wallpaper

I am developing a live wallpaper for Android. The wallpaper allocates some resources such as background bitmaps, sprites, textures, etc.

The question is: where should I allocate and initialize all of the resources? Should I allocate them in `WallpaperService.Engine` inherited object's constructor or `onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)` method?

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer is yes **SurfaceHolder** or **WallpaperService** . since explaining the whole method procedure is pretty huge.

Am gonna hook you up by some nice tutorials, just follow them
http://www.rajeeshcv.com/post/details/36/create-a-live-aquarium-wallpaper-in-android

Another one
http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.ae/2013/07/android-livewallpaer-tutorial.html